# Integration is only possible for forms and not for general tensors?

Tags: integration, differential-forms, tensors

Integration is only possible for forms and not for general tensors?
What is the true reason for this?
Or can integration of $k$-forms be extended in some natural way to arbitrary $(k,l)$ tensors;if so how this can be interpreted and defined?